# Machine learning with image data and a continuous output

Tags: r, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I have raw grey scale image files of an led light. I want to use a machine learning algorithm to output the intensity of the LED. I don’t know where to start, everything seems to focus on classification. I want a continuous output variable. I can calculate manually in imagej by estimating the region of interest around the LED and summing the pixel values but I don’t want to have to find the LED in every image and calculate its intensity. I want the algorithm to take the entire image as an input and output the intensity of that single feature. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. I have the images and the numerical outputs to train and test the model but don’t know where to start.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided a reproducible example. Here's a good link for getting started: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to have a solution only by applying image processing to detect the LED light and then extract, for example, the average intensities in the region, but if you really want to use ML, then you need to train the object detection model first. To do this you will need to make labeling in the regions of interest of the LED.